# Incompatible shapes when training a custom autoencoder. ([batch_size, img_height, img_widht, 3] vs. [batch_size])

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am currently working on an *autoencoder* for *anomaly detection*, and I keep running into the same error no matter what I try:

> Node: 'gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs'
> Incompatible shapes: [16,224,224,3] vs [16]

After spending time analyzing the problem and changing the machine I'm working on, it seems like the *mean squared error* `mse` tries to calculate the error between a batch of images `[16,224,224,3]` and an empty batch `[16]`.

I've shrunk my jupyter notebook to the bare minimum for posting here.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model

latent_dim = 64 

class Autoencoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim   
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)),
      layers.Rescaling(1./255),
      layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 1024, activation='relu', input_shape=(latent_dim,)),
      layers.Reshape((7, 7, 1024)),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', strides=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', strides=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', strides=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', strides=(2,2)),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 3, padding='same', activation='sigmoid', strides=(2,2)),
    ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dim)

data_dir = "Dataset"
img_height, img_width = 224, 224
batch_size = 16

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=42,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

autoencoder.fit(train_ds, epochs=10)
```

Here is the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
rescaling (Rescaling)        (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 1024)      4719616   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 1024)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 50176)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 50177     
=================================================================
Total params: 6,320,769
Trainable params: 6,320,769
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 50176)             100352    
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 7, 7, 1024)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 14, 14, 512)       4719104   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 28, 28, 256)       1179904   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 56, 56, 128)       295040    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 112, 112, 64)      73792     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 224, 224, 32)      18464     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DTr (None, 224, 224, 3)       867       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,387,523
Trainable params: 6,387,523
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution:

Since I had problems with calculating the loss between a batch of images and a "batch of labels", I simply replaced the labels (y) in the dataset with the image data (x).

```
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (x, x))
```

This might not be the most elegant solution, but now I can train the autoencoder. And since I don't need labels when using an autoencoder, I'm not missing anything.